# How do I find out which item in a watched array is changed in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

Let's say I have an array declared in the data section

```
data() {
   return {
      myData : [{foo:2, bar:3},{foo:4,bar:5}]
   }
}
```

When I change the `bar` property of the `second` element, I want to know that the second element was changed.

What would my watch function look like?

```
watch : {
  myData : {
     deep : true,
     handler(oldVal, newVal) {
      console.log("New val is the entire myData[] array which is not what I want", newVal);
      // I also want to know what index of the array the changed value belonged to.

     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First, your arguments are backwards on the watcher, as it should be `newVal, oldVal`

Also, I think this warning may apply here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch

```
Note: when mutating (rather than replacing) an Object or an Array, the old value will be the same as new value because they reference the same Object/Array. Vue doesn’t keep a copy of the pre-mutate value.
```

Comment: Nonetheless, how do I get the index of the array object that's being mutated?

Comment: I think that probably depends on how you are mutating the array in the first place